# Beta distribution from mean and quantile

Tags: r, excel, quantiles, beta-distribution

Suppose I'm given the mean and one quantile (e.g. the 20% quantile) of a random variable $x$, and I want to find the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of a Beta distribution that has the same mean and quantile.  Is there an efficient way to do it?

Using just the mean, I know that since $\bar{x} = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$, we have $\beta = \frac{\alpha}{\bar{x}} - \alpha$.  So we only really have one parameter to estimate.  But I'm unsure how to use the quantile information to take the next step.  Maybe there's something I can do with the Incomplete Beta when I know the ratio $\frac{\beta}{\alpha} = \frac{1-\bar{x}}{\bar{x}}$?

I have access to `R` myself, so I could use a numerical optimizer for this, but ideally I need a method that can be carried out in Excel in someone else's environment.  Excel does have `BETA.DIST()` and `BETA.INV()` functions available.  A look-up table would be fine, but a closed-form formula would be better if it's possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really have to do it with pesky Excel:

1. Create cells with quantile probability $p$, quantile value $q$, mean $m$.
2. Create a cell with some initial $\alpha$ value. Create a cell with formula $\beta=\left(\frac{1-m}{m}\right)\alpha$.
3. Create a cell with formula $\mathrm{abs}(q - \mathrm{beta.inv}(p, \alpha,\beta))$.
4. Go to "Data" > "What-If Analysis" > "Goal Seek". Choose the previous cell for item "Set cell", put $0$ in "To value", and choose the $\alpha$ cell for "By changing cell". Press "OK".
5. Next time: Use R! (I'm joking. I know you're an R user.)

Comment: There's a built-in Excel solver?  That I did not know.  I'll have to look at that, thanks.

Comment: I would of course use R myself - this is work for someone else who already has an Excel-based "workflow" they want to slot a little analysis step into.

Comment: Ken: I understand your suffering. Once I had to translate the Fortran code of R's built in loess regression function to VB. You can imagine how much that sucks.

Comment: +1 Note that (1) not all combinations of $(p,q,m)$ are even possible (even when individually their values make sense for Beta distributions) and (2) in Excel, solutions may be imprecise.